# ag-grid: highlight duplicated cell values

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-vue, datagridviewcellstyle

I am using ag-grid and I would like to highlight cells in a column if the cell values for a particular column are duplicated. The duplicated cells should be highlighted using a red border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the duplicate highlighting by iterating through the row data to detect the duplicate values and then pass the detected duplicates to a custom cellStyle function.

```js
  defaultColDef = {
    cellStyle: function(params) {
        const columnId = params.colDef.field;
        const currentValue = params.value;
        const duplicates = params.context.duplicates;

        if (columnId in duplicates && duplicates[columnId] == currentValue){
          return { 'background-color': 'red' };
        }
  
        return { 'background-color': null};
      }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    for (let key in this.rowData[0]) {
      let seenValues = new Set<string>()
      for (let i in this.rowData){
        const item = this.rowData[i]
        if (seenValues.has(item[key])){
          this.duplicates[key] = item[key];
        } else {
          seenValues.add(item[key]);
        }
      }
    }  
  }
```

Here is an example:

[image: Image of ag-grid highlighting duplicate values]

Here is the code for AngularJS:
[https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-duplicates-highlighting-6adsz6](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-duplicates-highlighting-6adsz6?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Here is the code for Vue:
[https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-highlight-duplicates-vue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-highlight-duplicates-vue?file=app.js)

Comment: hey ,thank you so much, did you have any idea for implementing same with vue.js

Comment: No problem, I've edited the post with a vue.js example.